# Websvn showing blank screen after adding svn binary location

Tags: php, svn, websvn

I installed SVN & configured just 2 things, after renaming `distconfig.php` to `config.php`

1. $config->setSVNCommandPath('D:\SlikSvn\bin\'); //  e.g. c:\program files\subversion\bin
2. $config->addRepository('Assembla', 'https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/projectname', null, 'username', 'passwd');

Inititally, it was showing me :

```
Error running this command: svn --config-dir /tmp --version

'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

After specifying the svn.exe path correctly using 1, it doesn't show any error, but a blank page.

I tried adding & removing 2, but it continues to show blank page.

Any idea on what might be going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It was a permissions issue, both websvn & silksvn (svn client) directories required permission setting.

Once giving full control to the IIS user, all worked perfectly.